# Chrome radial gradient not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gradient, radial-gradients

I'm using Chrome version 24.0.1312.25 beta-m and I'm trying to get a radial gradient for a small site, it doesn't seem to display correctly in Chrome.

The CSS I'm using is:

```
html {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(0, 0, 0));
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dHb.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And it's displaying as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbSuo.jpg

First of all, it's not radial. Secondly, there's a band directly in the center if you look closely.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dHb.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>​
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

  /* fallback */
  background-color: #2F2727;
  background-image: url(images/radial_bg.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
  /* Can't specify a percentage size? Laaaaaame. */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#FFFFFF), to(#000000));

  /* Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF, #000000);

  /* Firefox 3.6+ */ 
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF, #000000);

  /* IE 10 */ 
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #FFFFFF, #000000);

  /* Opera cannot do radial gradients yet */
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ETKpb/5/

Comment: It does give me a radial gradient like I need, but it has to be for the entire page. I can do linear gradients with the `html` css tag, I did that for another page.

Comment: @user1493839 this what you mean?